# bosh hosting for google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, xmpp, openfire

any recommendation on which company providing scalable bosh hosting?

p/s: is there exist any scalable jabber server +bosh service using openfire?

Comment: You want a host that provides an Openfire server with bosh service? Or you want to know if there's a good server out there to join? Openfire has built in bosh support, so you can set up your own jabber server and set that up, as shown here: 
http://www.malcollier.com/?p=14  or is they word scalable? I would just set up openfire on whatever host you go with, and make sure they are scalable in general.

Comment: i finding hosting company. openfire need extra plugin 'coherence' to scale. that's why i finding hosting company that already providing such service on scalable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

App Engine doesn't support 'hanging gets' - eg, long lived HTTP requests - so BOSH isn't possible over it. There's support for browser push (comet) on the roadmap, however.

Comment: @Nick thank you for the response. May i know for the upcoming push comet feature. can we use existing dwr library,atmosphere library or there will be new gae api for comet?

Comment: I don't know what a "dwr library" is, but it's likely that there will be a new API, similar to the XMPP API.

Comment: i so hope that google gonnna allow us to use existing comet library. If not the app will become so depending on gae that it can run standalone and not portable.. sad